# How to change the name of files according to left to right order on ls output?

Tags: linux, bash, substring

I have a directory in which I have files with the same suffix:

```
$ ls ./*.gbk
k141_1208254.region001.gbk 
k141_1374899.region001.gbk  
k141_1398938.region001.gbk  
k141_1444319.region001.gbk  
k141_46645.region001.gbk
```

I want to differentiate these files in another way, **changing .region00# according to left to right orientation**.

This is the desired output:

```
k141_1208254.region001.gbk 
k141_1374899.region002.gbk  
k141_1398938.region003.gbk  
k141_1444319.region004.gbk  
k141_46645.region005.gbk
```

There are several folder that have `*.gbk` files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
counter=1
for f in *.region001.gbk; do         # iterate over filenames ending in .region001.gbk
  [[ -e $f || -L $f ]] || {          # if we have a file that doesn't exist:
    echo "ERROR: $f not found" >&2   #  ...write an error message to stderr...
    exit 1                           #  ...and exit the script early.
  fi
  prefix=${f%.region001.gbk}         # strip the suffix off the name to get the prefix
  printf -v suffix 'region%03d.gbk'  # calculate a new suffix
  newName="${prefix}.${suffix}"      # append that to the prefix to get the new name
  if [[ $f != $newName ]]; then      # if that new name differs from the old name...
    mv -- "$f" "$newName"            #  ...then rename the file.
  fi
  (( ++counter ))                    # finally, increment the counter.
done
```

Note that not overwriting existing output files (if any `.region002` etc. files exist in the directory already) is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

[@Charles Duffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69429506/7376041) looks good and informative but I made the same thing with my poor bash knowledge.

Below code;

1. generate suffixes and save them to an array (001, 002, etc.)
2. make a loop for all .gbk files
3. parse necessary prefixes with regex from filename (like k141_1208259.region)
4. merge prefixes (k141_1208259.region) with suffixes (002) -> (like k141_1208259.region002)
5. rename the file by moving it

```sh
pad=1000; # 3 digit fixed

declare -a suffixes

file_count=$(ls -l *gbk  | wc -l)

for i in $(seq $file_count);
do ((j=pad+i))
    count=${j#?}
    suffixes+=($count)
done

iteration=0

for i in ./*.gbk ; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ ^.\/(([-_a-zA-Z0-9.]*.)region)[0-9]*(.gbk)$ ]];
    then
        mv "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${suffixes[iteration]}.gbk" ;
        ((iteration++))
    fi
done
```

This code maybe gives you an idea.

Comment: Not my downvote, but do see [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for a better-practice way to count files with a given extension (without needing to parse `ls` -- [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) goes into why that's considered a bad idea). Also, consider a [C-style for loop](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) instead of `seq` (which isn't a POSIX-standardized command; even though it's very widespread, it isn't guaranteed to be installed everywhere).

Comment: For a concrete example on the parsing-ls thing, some very simple implementations of `ls` will print the file created by `touch $'foo\nbar'` on two lines, so `wc -l` would think it was two separate files, one named `foo` and the other named `bar`.